# Ошибка при создании APK файла

Tags: android-studio

Добрый день!
При создании APK Файла мне в логе андроид студио пишет следующую ошибку. Как ее исправить?

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\2.0\MyBusiness31\MyBusiness31\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:Error: Permission name C2D_MESSAGE is not unique (appears in both com.d2o.onedateapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE and com.loveapps.znakomstvaryadom.permission.C2D_MESSAGE) [UniquePermission]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
          // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
          // but continue the build even when errors are found:
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
Information:BUILD FAILED in 50s
```

Comment: покажите свой манифест

Comment: Что значит манифест?

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml` - (facepalm)

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.loveapps.znakomstvaryadom.test">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24"/>
<application android:debuggable="true">
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
</application>
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="com.loveapps.znakomstvaryadom" android:handleProfiling="false" android:functionalTest="false" android:label="Tests for com.loveapps.znakomstvaryadom"/>
</manifest>

Comment: Это не полный манифест, а его часть. Покажите полный манифест, скорее всего он генерируется из нескольких частей - загляните в каталог `build/intermediates`

Comment: Видимо да потому, что где вы просили посмотреть там талько он один. Однако когда я ввожу в поиск в папке, то их открывается минимум штук 10. И как мне быть?

Comment: Если вы разработчик, то наверное вы мне должны сказать на какой из них смотреть :) Там на каждый `flavour/build type` генерируется свой. Если вы не разработчик, то мы с вами не договоримся.

Comment: Ну да я не разработчик. И как мне быть?))

Comment: Зовите разработчика, иначе бесполезно

Comment: Разработчика не знаю где взять, куда-то пропал.

Answer (score 4):

По строчке:

> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

Поняно что сработал **Lint** - это довольно полезная штука для отлова потенциальных багов. Инфу о нем можно посмотреть тут: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint.

У меня лично он, ругался на ошибки в ресурсах, которые возникли при переводе на несколько языков.

Найти же причину ошибки можно открыв отчет линта. Который находится как правило по адресу:

***"Папка с проектами AndroidStudio" / "Название Вашего проекта" /app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html***

Когда нет времени разбираться, а релиз нужен уже вчера, то отключить можно так:

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        //put this piece of code here:
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
              ...
       <--Other your config-->
    }
}
```

Потом все же стоит заглянуть в отчет линта и пофиксить потенциальную багу.

**UPD:**
Кстати, сам `Lint` подсказывает вариант решения (отключения проверки):

> ```
> To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:    
>    ...    
>    android {
>        lintOptions {
>            checkReleaseBuilds false
>            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>            abortOnError false
>        }       
>    }
> ```